# IAM policy with ec2 full access not allowing to create EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, policy

An IAM user created with policy EC2fullaccess is not allowed to create ec2 instances in any other region except N.virginia . What could be the reason ?

Policy attached to the user :

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": "ec2:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "cloudwatch:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "autoscaling:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "iam:AWSServiceName": [
                    "autoscaling.amazonaws.com",
                    "ec2scheduled.amazonaws.com",
                    "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com",
                    "spot.amazonaws.com",
                    "spotfleet.amazonaws.com",
                    "transitgateway.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Perhaps this policy has an `aws:RequestedRegion` global condition key restricting you to N. Virginia: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easier-way-to-control-access-to-aws-regions-using-iam-policies/

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what privileges your superuser/root account has? While I don't know of any accounts being limited to us-east-1 by default, I can see someone setting that up for security reasons - in fact, if it's possible I might do so myself.

The other possibility, while I don't see it in that JSON snippet, is that your entire account is limited to us-east-1, and that that rule trumps the EC2 permission outside of N. Virginia.